# How to Install android-pdfview Android Studio

Tags: android, pdf

I need to show a PDF document in an activity of my android app. So I found this library called android-pdfview.

[Link to android-pdfview library](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview)

But its not clear to me how to install this library into android studio and use it.

So can anyone please guide me through how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: link you provided is not working

Comment: I don't understand where is the confusion. The github link you provided already has everything you need to get started!

Comment: @Vivek Sorry about that... it's fixed now

Comment: @camelCaseCoder first of all how to install the whole thing... in the link it just says... via gradle(I assume this one will go with android studio) following a project name.

then there's sample code of how to load a PDF. and in the example, onLoadCompleteListener and onPageChangeListener
I can understand these are some event handlers but I can't find any reference regarding how to implement them.

Comment: Try [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) and [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Comment: https://plugpdf.com/plugpdf-android-devguide/ see this link very useful for pdf reader..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install, paste this in your `build.gradle` file:

`compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'`

Then add it to your activity layout file like this:

```
<com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And then get an instance of the `PDFView` object in your activity and call the `load()` method passing the `URI` of your file and the `OnLoadCompleteListener` reference (you'll implement this in your activity).

Also, you can use various methods of the `PDFView` class to set configuration options. Have a look at the [PDFView](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/blob/master/android-pdfview/src/main/java/com/joanzapata/pdfview/PDFView.java) class.

Comment: but Now as I've tried to open the a file from external storage it gives me this error...

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PDF file is corrupted :/

the PDF is ok.. it works on other apps

here's the code
https://ideone.com/Yex3io

Comment: Did you try with some other PDF?

Comment: There is an open issue (https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/issues/23) regarding this which the developer says is because of the VuDroid library that it uses.

Comment: I've solved the issue it required the storage permission... It should have some thing like "FileNotFoundException" but it showed "pdf corrupted".. that got me confused... :/ anyway appreciate your help :)

Comment: Glad your problem is solved! Might wanna mark the answer as accepted? :)

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same error "com.joanzapata.pdfview.exception.FileNotFoundException" what should I do about it? :(

Comment: @KairiSan are you sure the path is correct? If yes, then create a new question with proper details and complete logcat.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem not too long ago. I found no fully functional library. All solutions lacked some functionality and there is no native way in the android libraries.

You should try to display the info with some other view type, rebuild it with normal views, include images or use html for a webview.

If you have to use the pdf, the preferred way is to send out an intent and let the system handle it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(openedFile), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Sorry. But please post your solution if you really find a good library that is not too large and supports all pdf functionalities.

Comment: Thank you for your help... but I need to show the PDF inside my Activity. I don't really have any other options :(

Comment: It might not help, but I ended up downloading the pdf to the sd card and then sending the file with an intent so the user can view it in his own pdf-reader. Good luck with finding a good library. The pdf-library is working, but for me it kept cutting off some parts of the pdf, so just try if it works with your files.

Comment: I know that way... and I really wish I could do that... but the app involves data security encryption decryption kinda things... so I cant handle the task using users PDF reader. How ever... I've solved the issue with the library stated in the main post... for now it will do the job... anyway appreciate your help :)